# Qt: What's the best way to swap QGraphicsRectItem positions

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, sorting, swap

---

I'm creating a visualization of sorting algorithms.
I've got a vector of `QGraphicsRectItems` which are columns with different height and the same width, generated on the app start. They are being shuffled and then added to a `QGraphicsScene`.
Class named "algorithms" sort a vector of float values which are used to set a height of columns. On swap - it emits a signal to the main class with two integers, so it looks like this:

```
emit comparison(array[first element to swap], array[second element to swap]);
```

Function(on_comparison) in the main class is connected with that signal. The problem appeared when I was trying to swap these 2 elements. I've created a variable to set `n` column position to it. After that I was trying to setPos of columns so I did something like:

```
void on_comparision(int n, int k)
{
   auto nColumnPos = columns[n]->pos().x();
   columns[n]->setX(columns[k]->pos().x());
   columns[k]->setX(nColumnPos);
}
```

But it doesn't work. Positions are not changing.
Furthermore

```
qDebug() <<nColumnPos;
```

shows value = 0.

I was wondering if my whole program works so I decided to implement 2 sorting algorithms which swap 2 near each other elements and modified `on_comparison` function to

```
columns[n]->setX(columns[n].pos().x() + columnsWidth);
columns[n]->setX(columns[n].pos().x() - columnsWidth);
```

It works but doesn't give a satisfying result. This function will work only with sorting algorithms that swap 2 near each other elements except eg. Bubblesort/cocktailsort.

I was searching for the answer but didn't find anything helpful.

---

Here's the code:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e612e35a7c14eeb650099d4b997f437d

---

Comment: You must upload the file .ui and the main.cpp, in addition to the .pro.

Comment: @eyllanesc there is a folder with all source files https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1be3QrYwCdfb5qKCfIVIa0wPl5CPtLPcP?usp=sharing

Comment: You say it works with those 2 algorithms, and I see that it works, my question, in what case does it not work?

Comment: `void on_comparision(int n, int k)
{
   auto nColumnPos = columns[n]->pos().x();
   columns[n]->setX(columns[k]->pos().x());
   columns[k]->setX(nColumnPos);
   std::swap(columns[n], columns[k]);
}` that's the function that I was trying to use, but columns are not even moving.

Comment: `columns[n]->setX(columns[n].pos().x() + columnsWidth);
columns[n]->setX(columns[n].pos().x() - columnsWidth);` 
And that's a function that works only with Bubble sort and cocktail Sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem. The on_comparision function should look like this:

```
auto nRect = columns[n]->rect();
auto kRect = columns[k]->rect();
auto nColumnPos = nRect.left();
auto kColumnPos = kRect.left();

nRect.moveLeft(kColumnPos);
kRect.moveLeft(nColumnPos);

columns[n]->setRect(nRect);
columns[k]->setRect(kRect);
std::swap(columns[n], columns[k]);
```

instead of

```
auto nColumnPos = columns[n]->pos().x();
columns[n]->setX(columns[k]->pos().x());
columns[k]->setX(nColumnPos);
std::swap(columns[n], columns[k]);
```